# Filter Grayscale not working with Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have a link in my HTML page which is an image, and is transitionning from fully grayscale to partially grayscale on hover.

Here is the HTML a bit simplified:

```
<div id="myid">
    <a href="targetlinkhere"><img alt="" class="rounded" src="imglinkhere" /></a>
</div>
```

and my CSS :

```
#myid a:link,#myid a:active,#myid a:visited{
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-filter ease 1s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-filter ease 1s;
  -o-transition: -o-filter ease 1s;
  -ms-transition: -ms-filter ease 1s;
  transition: filter ease 1s;
}

#myid a:hover {
  filter: grayscale(20%);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(20%);
  -moz-filter: grayscale(20%);
  -ms-filter: grayscale(20%);
  -o-filter: grayscale(20%);
}
```

Everything works fine with Firefox but Chrome doesnt apply any filter at all. And doesn't transition either. 
Though when I apply the above code to `#myid img` then the filter is applyed to the image.

Is it not right to apply a filter to an `a` tag ?

Comment: Chrome expects  a value between 0 and 1 like opacity.  % does not work.
It is best to stick to that for now

Answer (score 4):

For those using sass or something similar, it's possible the grayscale function (and others) are overridden. The solution then would be to use a mixin untill they fix these issues.

```
@mixin grayscale($value) {
    filter: #{ "grayscale(" + $value + ")" };
}

.nav-link {
    transition: filter ease 0.5s;

    &:hover,
    &:active,
    &:focus {
        img {
            @include grayscale(100%);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Another similar solution is to use `unquote`: `filter: unquote("grayscale(100%)");`. See here: https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/314#issuecomment-51896758

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're inadvertently overriding the property. Try this:

```
#myid a {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-filter ease 1s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-filter ease 1s;
  -ms-transition: -ms-filter ease 1s;
  -o-transition: -o-filter ease 1s;
  transition: filter ease 1s;
}

#myid a:hover {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(20%);
  -moz-filter: grayscale(20%);
  -ms-filter: grayscale(20%);
  -o-filter: grayscale(20%);
  filter: grayscale(20%);
}
```

or, if you want to keep your current selectors, like this:

```
#myid a:link, #myid a:active, #myid a:visited {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-filter ease 1s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-filter ease 1s;
  -ms-transition: -ms-filter ease 1s;
  -o-transition: -o-filter ease 1s;
  transition: filter ease 1s;
}

#myid a:hover, #myid a:link:hover, #myid a:active:hover, #myid a:visited:hover {
 -webkit-filter: grayscale(20%);
  -moz-filter: grayscale(20%);
  -ms-filter: grayscale(20%);
  -o-filter: grayscale(20%);
  filter: grayscale(20%);
}
```

Edit: so, the problem is that you need to set your `a` element to be a block level element, as it contains a block level `img` as a child.

```
#myid a {
    display: block; /* or inline-block would probably work too */
    /*
    All your filter stuff here
    */
}
```

Comment: Both still work with Firefox but not with Chrome. I have replaced `a` by `img` and everything work fine in both (`#myid img` and `#myid img:hover`). Definitely think Chrome doesn't like filters on `a` tag :/

Comment: That's very strange. Any chance you'd be willing to show me the code you're working on, on JSFiddle or something? I'm genuinely curious.

Comment: Tried this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fmzxq6yh/ definitely works in Chrome. I checked CSS rule located above the two mentioned here:  `#myid img`. Seems I found the problem: `display: block;` When applied to the inner image, it disable filter in Chrome but not in Firefox. another glitch it seems :/

Comment: updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fmzxq6yh/1/ I will try not to use display: block for this image. I may still be able to position it properly ..

Comment: Ah, yes. That's because the `a` tag is `display: inline` by default, and an inline element cannot have a block level child. Setting `#myid a { display: block }` should fix the issue. [Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fmzxq6yh/2/)

Comment: Does work ! I get perfect positioning and link behaving correctly. Though I get a long underline spanning the whole Div when I hover. It's not removed by `text-decoration: none;` I Think I will just go back to my idea of applying the filter and transition to  the image tag instead of the a tag. It brings me too far ! Many thanks for clarifiying the problem. Chrome has no issue then ^^

Comment: I could probably speculate what's going on there too, but yes, applying the filter to the image would probably be the best solution. :)